# How do I import the Foldable class into my module?

Tags: haskell

The following import statement causes a conflict with foldr et al. because the first import statement seems to import all the functions in Data.Foldable into my module:

```
import Data.Foldable (Foldable (..))
import qualified Data.Foldable as Foldable (foldr, foldl, foldr1, foldl1, foldMap)
```

This import statement seems to work.  However the Foldable class is now Foldable.Foldable:

```
import qualified Data.Foldable as Foldable (Foldable (..), foldr, foldl, foldr1, foldl1, foldMap)
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `foldr` etc. are class methods of `Foldable`, hence they're imported unqualified by `import Data.Foldable (Foldable(..))` in the first variant.
To only import the class unqualified, not its methods, use

```
import Data.Foldable (Foldable)
import qualified Data.Foldable as Foldable
```

Comment: Thanks!  I use to take (..) for granted.  Now I have found a reason to respect it.  :-)

Answer (score 2):

you have to hide foldr from Prelude module

```
import Prelude hiding (foldr)
```